# Esperar pelos resultados de métodos assíncronos do Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, assincronismo

Estou tendo frequentemente problemas em vários trechos de código onde necessito fazer chamadas a métodos assíncronos da biblioteca do Firebase Database.

A questão é que estes métodos muitas vezes não retornam seus resultados antes da View ser carregada e, em alguns casos, esses resultados são necessários para carregar corretamente elementos para o app rodar.

Segue um exemplo:

```
public void validarLogin() {
    autenticacao = ConfigFirebase.getFirebaseAutenticacao();
    autenticacao.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            usuario.getEmail(),
            usuario.getSenha()
    ).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()) {

                id_user_logado = Base64Custom.codificarBase64(usuario.getEmail());

                firebase = ConfigFirebase.getFirebase().child("usuario").child(id_user_logado);
                valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        // Salvando usuário logado nas preferêncais
                        Usuario usuario_recuperado = dataSnapshot.getValue(Usuario.class);

                        Preferencias preferencias = new Preferencias(LoginEmailActivity.this);
                        preferencias.salvarPreferencias(id_user_logado, usuario_recuperado.getNome());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                };

                firebase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bem-vindo!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                abrirTelaPrincipal(); // Uma Intent que chama outra Activity
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "E-mail ou senha inválidos!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

No caso acima, eu confirmo a autenticação do usuário no Firebase, esta é confirmada e o **Toast de "Bem-vindo" é carregado**. Todavia, no tempo em que o método **abrirTelaPrincipal()** é chamado, o **addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)** ainda não fez a consulta. Desta forma, minha outra *Activity é carregada antes da completude do meu método assíncrono*, fazendo com que as instruções que estão dentro deste não sejam executadas.

Por vezes, sem os dados deste métodos, minha aplicação vai somando problemas nos métodos síncronos.

**A questão é:** qual a forma mais adequada para garantir que os retornos de métodos assíncronos do Firebase sejam recebidos antes que a aplicação siga seu fluxo sem estes dados?

Answer (score 1):

Seu toast e a intent devem ser chamadas dentro do onDataChange, que é o momento que vc possui todas as informações necessárias.

```
 preferencias.salvarPreferencias(id_user_logado, usuario_recuperado.getNome());
```

Você deve chamar após essa linha.

Provavelmente vc precisará usar o `runOnUiThread` você pode encontrar um exemplo [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11140429/4250648).

Pq é necessário chamar dentro do `onDataChange`?
Como você mesmo falou é um método assíncrono ou seja leva um tempo para obter uma resposta (fazer uma solicitação ao servidor do firebase e aguardar ele responder).

O que você deve fazer é colocar alguma mensagem de aguarde(*loading*) e que force o usuário a esperar a requisição ao Firebase.

Comment: Está corretíssimo. Mas acho que o `runOnUiThread` não é necessário.